# AngularJS plugin for Webstorm not sticking

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I have installed WebStorm 7 for Windows successfully, and have been playing with Angularjs projects. I wanted to install the AngularJS plugin. I opened File/Settings/Plugins, and the AngularJS plugin was not listed, so I pressed Browse Repositories, found it, and installed it. It then showed up in my list, highlighted in green. When I hit OK WebStorm asks if I want to restart to integrate the plugin, and I do. But when I open WebStorm again, the plugin is no longer listed. I tried once more, same result. Any idea what incantation I need to do? ;) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [installing plugins document](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html).

There could be some issue with installing the plugin, check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for possible errors.

As a workaround you can [download plugin zip](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971?pr=idea) manually and unpack it into the [plugins directory](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108).

I've verified that on my system this plugin [appears in the list of installed plugins](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/1762/htx1.png) after IDE restart.